# Interceptor not working in JAX-rs project

Tags: java, jax-rs, javabeans, interceptor

I'm using websphere liberty. Gradle project. Jax-rs spec. Trying to get a simple interceptor to work. For example:

```
@Interceptor
@Logged
public class LoggedInterceptor {

    @AroundInvoke
    public Object logMethodEntry(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Entering method: " + invocationContext.getMethod().getName());
        Object result = invocationContext.proceed();
        System.out.println("Exiting method: " + invocationContext.getMethod().getName());
        return result;
    }
}
```

and then the customer annotation:

```
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Logged {
}
```

Then I register it (as i assume I have to do) to my main class that extends Application. So for this example the getClasses would return the LoggedInterceptor.class. Then I annotate a test class as so:

```
public class Test {
    String prop;

    @Logged
    public void setProp(String prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
    }
}
```

This is no bueno. Anything and everything I've tried has not worked. I must be missing something.